# Add marker over scatter chart plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I want to add a point to a plotly scatter plot to highlight specific value.

One of the ways to do it from what I have found is the following. But the issue is that new trace is placed *under* the main scatter chart. Is there any way to set the order so the "level" is always on top?

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from plotly import graph_objects as go

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (5000, 2)), columns=["x", "y"])

fig = px.scatter(data, x= "x", y="y")

fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=[data.iloc[10, 0]],
                y=[data.iloc[10, 1]],
                mode="markers",
                marker=dict(
                    color="red",
                    size=10,
                ),
                name="level"
            )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a subtle issue with first trace being created as **scattergl**.  Below recreates figure where first trace is modified to be **scatter**

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from plotly import graph_objects as go

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (5000, 2)), columns=["x", "y"])

fig = px.scatter(data, x= "x", y="y")

fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=[data.iloc[10, 0]],
                y=[data.iloc[10, 1]],
                mode="markers",
                marker=dict(
                    color="red",
                    size=10,
                ),
                name="level"
            )
)

d = fig.to_dict()
d["data"][0]["type"] = "scatter"

go.Figure(d)
```

[image]